To understand the use of "bei" with brechen
This sentence appears in my Der Anschlag, translated from S. King:

An einem frostigen Dezembertag brach bei meinem Ford schließlich ein Stößel,

The English sentence to which it corresponds is

Finally, on a chilly day in mid-December, my Ford threw a rod,

I am wondering about the use of "bei". Looking at the examples given by DWDS under the entry for brechen

das Brett bricht bei der Belastung


das Herz bricht mir bei dem Anblick

it seems as if bei is used to indicate how the break arises, or its cause. However, in the sentence from my reading it clearly is used to refer to what the break happens to, not how it is caused. Why is not "in" used instead?

It's tricky. 'In meinem Auto brach eine Pleuelstange"(*) lets the reader assume within interior space of the car (either front seats or back seats) something broke. In order to allow this distinction, one thus uses 'bei' or rarely 'an' when referring to something which is part of the vehicle itself.
The same logic applies similarily to things within or part of a building respectively. The distinction is not always clear though: "Bei meinem Haus ist eine Tür kaputt" has nearly the same meaning as "In meinem Haus ist eine Tür kaputt" - the latter makes clear its not one of the outward-facing doors, but an internal one, while I'd assume it's an outward-facing door when using 'bei'.
This distinction is not limited to things breaking, but works for other contexts, too: Bei meinem Auto sind die Sitze aus Leder und der Tank ist rechts. (My car has leather seats and the fuel tank is on the right).
Maybe one can say that 'bei' is used to indicate that the action is locally or temporally placed (in time or space) by the word indicated with 'bei': "Beim Einlaufen habe ich mir den Fuss verstaucht". The "Beim Einlaufen" is a kind of temporal description when it happens, but not causal. Similar the "Beim Auto ist etwas kaputt gegangen" is a localising description where something happens. In both cases no big detail is given, only the general place (in time or space), thus not "Am Anfang des Einlaufens..." = "at the beginning of running..." nor a detailed "Im Motor (des Autos) ist..." = "in the engine (of the car) is..."
(*) I believe that the right translation for "rod" in this context is Pleuelstange or Pleuel. Maybe I'm wrong and it's something else, but I'm reasonably sure that 'Stößel' is wrong or a bad translation by a technically unknowledgable person (which IMHO makes it close to ununderstandable to a German-speaking person what broke).

Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by, "lets the reader assume within the room for the people something broke." What room are you referring to?

The room where you and other passengers sit. The passenger space.Is there a good name for it?

Oh, I see. That would be the "interior of the car". It is never referred to as a room. It is also referred to as the front seat and the back seat, but both together would be the interior. Thanks for the clarification.

It doesn't matter for the answer, but actually "rod" could be both, a "Pleuel" and a "Stößel": a "Pleuel" is most commonly the part connecting the piston with the crankshaft. A "Stößel" is usually called a "tappet" or "valve lifter" and is the part to move the valve of a cylinder up and down. There are mecahnically moved ones (by a "camshaft") and there are ones ("Hydrostößel", "hydraulic tappet") with hydraulic regulation of the valve clearance ("Ventilspielausgleich").

I'm wondering, then, if a native German speaker reads the sentence from my reading, he has to figure out whether the bei refers to the cause or the location of the break? Is it immediately self-evident to the native speaker?

Bei is very often used to indicate location, for example Ich war beim Bäcker einkaufen = I went shopping at the bakery (literally: at the baker). This is the primary usage of bei. Indicating the cause of something is less frequent. From the noun preceded by bei it is generally easy to tell whether it's location or cause.

'bei' is never causal. More locally or temporally-descriptive, in a wider sense. So also like "Beim Einlaufen habe ich mir den Fuss verstaucht". The "Beim Einlaufen" is a kind of temporal description when it happens, but not causal. Similar the "Beim Auto..." is a local description where something happens.


My Ford threw a rod.

Here, my Ford is the subject and a rod is the direct object of threw.

Bei meinem Ford brach ein Stößel.

Here on the other hand, bei meinem Ford is a locational adverbial and ein Stößel is the subject. I would have written an meinem Ford instead but bei is also commonly used for this.
So the German phrasing is completely different from the English one. This is due to the different perspective on what happened.


das Brett bricht bei der Belastung

Here, bei der Belastung is an adverbial of circumstance.

das Herz bricht mir bei dem Anblick

Same here. Bei dem Anblick is also an adverbial of circumstance.

I am troubled by your use of the word "circumstance" here. Circumstance covers all factors pertaining to the situation, including both location and cause. So it is not clear to me how the reader is to know that "bei meinem Auto" means the location, and not the cause. The exemplars for brechen in DWDS seem to indicate that "an" should be used to indicate location and "bei" should be used to indicate cause.

There isn't a clear cut. Bei can be used for locations as well, e.g. Wir treffen uns beim Italiener. Likewise those DWDS examples aren't stricly causes but more a general sort of circumstance. If you wanted to mark a cause, you had to use wegen. But that's too determined and less common.
